# Javascript .children.length() returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

Javascript `.children.length()` returns wrong value i.e. 0 while if I use .firstNode then there is a text node available.

Please help me out in this.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you post an example of your code?

Comment: Well for starters it's `.children()`

Comment: And `.length()` is not a function. So you want to use `.length`

Comment: @PatsyIssa: We're not talking about jQuery, but about the DOM.

Comment: @Bergi my bad didn't pay attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.children` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) doesn't include text nodes, but only elements. You might be looking for [`.childNodes.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes) or simply [`.hasChildNodes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.hasChildNodes) instead.